# How to call a view on click of each UITableViewCell programmatically?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have created a UITableViewcontroller and a UINavigationController in a TableController.m
with UITableviewCell set to say @"CellOne" @"CellTwo". Now I also created two other files

```
`ImageView1.m`
  ImageView2.m
```

where if I click on CellOne I should be able to get the view placed on ImageView1.m, same applied to the ImageView2.m. How should I achieve this programmatically without using nib file?

Answer (score 1):

override the touches event in ImageView1 and ImageView2.

Comment: No i dont want it that way, I should be able to call another class only through the click of each row in the Table.Please give a coding example